# check JsonObject if it empty text

Tags: java, json

I have some problem with JSONObject.
I would like to check it on empty. For example :

```
{...., "type:"",...}.
```

When I have `{...., "type:null,...}.` I can check it the following..

```
 JSONObject thenBy = !configSwitch.isNull("thenBy") ? configSwitch.getJSONObject("thenBy") : new JSONObject();
```

Now I would like to check if type !="", how can I do it?

Comment: @Joel, "" is a perfectly valid JSON String value. { "test": "" } is a valid object.

Comment: jsonObject.getString("type").equals("");